# Xcode unit test -- setup and teardown only once

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

Is it possible to setup a unit test class to call setup and teardown methods only once for all the test cases not for each test case?

Comment: If you're using OCUnit and SenTestCase, that's not how setup and tearDown are designed to work.  You will probably have to define separate test classes for each test if you want this behavior.  But is it really necessary?  Are you worried about performance of doing a setup and teardown for each test?

Comment: Yeah my real concern is the performance. Consider a FileService class. In order to test the use cases I need to create and delete file in most of the methods. Instead I just want it to be created once and deleted at the end of all test cases.

Comment: I stand corrected.  ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually I found the answer. In order to do class level setup, one needs to implement `+(void) setUp` and `+(void) tearDown`. This class methods will be called before any test methods run and after all of the test methods run.

Comment: I believe you mean "implement" instead of "call".

Comment: but your question is "setup and teardown only once"?

Answer (score 0):

Check this from [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/testing_3_writing_test_classes/testing_3_writing_test_classes.html)

[image: Flow of Execution for XCTest]